# Return view from another post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var viewModel = service.GetUserViewModel(id);
   return View(viewModel); // reponse the ValidateLogin view
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditDetails(UserDetails userDetails)
{
    return Edit(userDetails.Id);
}
```

Unfortunelly it is not returning view, but it is giving me error. What's wrong there?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Returning in a **Post** request?

Comment: What's the error? I think it is perfectly alright. Can you please tell what is the error, then I can help you

Comment: I have a feeling that userDetails is null, but we can only know if you tell us what the error is. I am not sure why you kept this information to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return view from another action marked with `[HttpPost]` by using `return Edit(userDetails.Id)`, instead it's necessary to set one action as `[HttpGet]` (i.e. `Edit` action method) and use [`RedirectToAction()` overload which has route value parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29) to call that action like example below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditDetails(UserDetails userDetails)
{
    // note: the second overload is routeValues
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", userDetails.Id);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var viewModel = service.GetUserViewModel(id);
   return View(viewModel); // reponse the ValidateLogin view
}
```

Comment: Actually it is working. I just had to use `View("Edit", viewModel);` instead of `View(viewModel);`